# Need assistance regarding UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I created a simple app with two views, main or first view containing a button which simply call this code

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.secondView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [self.webView setDelegate:self];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wowza.com/_h264/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"]];
        //@"http://www.thumbafon.com/code_examples/video/segment_example/prog_index.m3u8"]];
        [[self webView]loadRequest:request];

    }];
```

All works fine but as video start playing I get this in console

```
<MPSwipableView: 0x1e043790; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1e043d30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e043850>>'s window is not equal to <ViewController: 0x1e017d80>'s view's window!
```

What this means? why I am getting this? and how to fix it?

Comment: Try not to transition the self.view? Create a new view to be transitioned which contains the button and add it to subview of self.view.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem just **check the box "Wants Full Screen"** on the **storyboard**.

or you can use...

```
[self addChildViewController:navVC];
[navVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[mainView addSubview:navVC.view];
```

Where , self = Parent view controller,
       navVC = Child view controller you are adding, 
    mainView = view in parent view controller to which you are going to add child view controller's view.

The problem appears because the ParentViewController is showing the navigation bar.

As Apple Documentation says :

> If your app displays the status bar, the view shrinks so that it does
>   not underlap the status bar. After all, if the status bar is opaque,
>   there is no way to see or interact with the content lying underneath
>   it. However, if your app displays a translucent status bar, you can
>   set the value of your view controller’s wantsFullScreenLayout property
>   to YES to allow your view to be displayed full screen. The status bar
>   is drawn over the top of the view.

Comment: but I have no navigation controller, no navigation bar. Its just a single view app, I add an secondUIView which contains my webview and thats all.

Comment: @S.J : Are you using Storyboards ?

Comment: No I am not using story Board

Comment: its just a single view app, In interface builder I added another uiview and add the webview on it, Using [uiview transitionfromview... I am bringing the secondview to display, but I am gettign that warning that i mention in my question.

Comment: @S.J : Do you have "Auto Layout" feature ON ? Check it : http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/

Comment: @S.J : Make "Autoresize Subviews" ON.